# Are there other solutions to the functional equation $f(x,y)\circ f(y,x)=e$?

Tags: group-theory, functional-equations

Let $(G,\circ)$ be a group with identity $e$. We want to solve for $f$ in the functional equation $$f(x,y)\circ f(y,x)=e\qquad \forall x,y \in G$$

A trivial solution is $f(x,y) := e$. Working backwards from known examples for $(\mathbb R, +)$ and  $(\mathbb R_+, \cdot)$, I see that two possible solutions are:
$$ f(x,y) := x \circ y^{-1}$$  and $$ f(x,y) := y \circ x^{-1}$$

Are there any other solutions, or can it be shown that these are the only two non-trivial solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f\colon X\times X\to G$ where $X$ is an arbitrary non-empty set. Define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X\times X$ by $(x,y)\sim (u,v)$ iff $\{ x,y\}=\{u,v\}$, Then the equivalence classes are of the form $\{(x,x)\}$ or of the form $\{(x,y),(y,x)\}$ with $x\not=y$. Then all functions $f$ such that $f(x,x)\circ f(x,x)=e$ for all $x$ and $f(x,y)\circ f(y,x)=e$ for all $x\not=y$ have the desired property. Thus you may define $f$ according to these rules on the equivalence classes. But there is no need to have relations between different classes.

Comment: I didn't understand the part after defining the equivalence classes. Do you mean to say we map each equivalence class to an element $g$ of the group such that $g \circ g = e$?

Comment: This has to hold true for classes containing only one element. In the other case you may choose $f(x,y)$ arbitrarily and then put $f(y,x):=f(x,y)^{-1}$. If, for example $X=G=\mathbb{R}$ we may define $f$ by $f(x,x)=0$ for all $x$ and by $f(x,y)=x^2$ and $f(y,x)=-x^2$ if $x<y$.